# Space at the top of the page (Twitter Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a space at the page's top and I don't know how to remove it.

I have created background image (1,2) in my page example. 
But I'm not able to find what the source of this white line. I have modified a lot of settings in css with no result.

#### [Demo in Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/bv6z3uUZRW)

Here's my code:

```html
<section id="first">
    <h1>TEST!</h1> <br>
</section>
<section id="first1">
    <h1>TEST2!</h1> <br>
</section>
```

```css
#first {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/37FDFC/&text=photo1) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 800px;
    /*height: 800px;*/
    /*padding-bottom: 200px;*/
}

#first1 {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/FFFF00/&text=photo2) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 800px;
    /*height: 800px;*/
    /*padding-bottom: 200px;*/
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle is a mess ... Use Bootply instead http://www.bootply.com/wpTtMWUUYR don't need to include css or js files of bootstrap

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/bv6z3uUZRW

Comment: That is because all h1-h6 tags have a top margin. Either remove the margin on that specific h1 or add top padding to the parent

Comment: Yes, exactly. It works. Thank you. You are master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to highlight what Christina said, this issue is being caused by the `top-margin` on your `h1` element:

[image: screenshot]

#### Here's a cleaned up version that replicates the problem

```css
.background-photo {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
  min-height: 800px;  
}

#first {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/37FDFC/&text=photo1);
}
#second {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/FFFF00/&text=photo2);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="first" class="background-photo">
  <h1>TEST!</h1>
</section>
<section id="second" class="background-photo">
  <h1>TEST2!</h1>
</section>
```

You can fix it by doing either of the following:

#### 1) Adding sufficient padding to the containing section:

```css
.background-photo {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```css
.background-photo {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
  min-height: 800px;  
}

#first {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/37FDFC/&text=photo1);
}
#second {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/FFFF00/&text=photo2);
}

.background-photo {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="first" class="background-photo">
  <h1>TEST!</h1>
</section>
<section id="second" class="background-photo">
  <h1>TEST2!</h1>
</section>
```

#### 2) Removing the Margin on the header:

```css
.background-photo h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```css
.background-photo {
  background: no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
  min-height: 800px;  
}

#first {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/37FDFC/&text=photo1);
}
#second {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/FFFF00/&text=photo2);
}

.background-photo h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="first" class="background-photo">
  <h1>TEST!</h1>
</section>
<section id="second" class="background-photo">
  <h1>TEST2!</h1>
</section>
```